# Why is this copy Stream larger than its original Stream?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, stream

I'm trying to modify a file stream and I came across something interesting. When I read a string out of the original stream and then attempt to write it into a new stream, I end up with a larger size than the original.

I did not find any similar questions.  Can someone clarify what is happening? I stepped through and noted the sizes of the variables

```
private Stream CopyAndChangeStreamContents(Stream input)
{
    input.Position = 0; //input.Length is (long)84863 

    string contents = new StreamReader(input).ReadToEnd(); //contents.Length is (int)80765 

    Stream output = new MemoryStream();
    new StreamWriter(output).Write(contents); //output.Length is (long)151950 

    output.Flush();
    return output;
}
```

**EDIT #2**
Downvoter: The comments and intention of the method do not explain what is happening here. Regardless of what type of data is being read, **I want to understand what underlying stream feature is causing such drastic size differences**.

When reading bytes, it does not matter if it comes from a zip or a text file, bytes are still bytes, so if I have an input `0110 0001 0110 0010 0110 0011 0110 0100` I would expect to still be reading 4 bytes. Even if I read this as the string 'abcd', it should not make a difference to me if I write the binary back exactly as I found it.

**Why does one Stream give me a length of 84863 while another stream gives me a length of 151950?**

**EDIT**:
I tried using StreamReader constructor that attempts to read encoding:

`var reader = new StreamReader(input, true);`

and later using that same encoding when writing out:

`new StreamWriter(output, reader.CurrentEncoding).Write(contents);`

..To no avail. Same issue.

Comment: The original source file is probably ASCII, but you are writing UTF8. If you only want to copy files, you shouldn't treat them as text.

Comment: As such `input.CopyTo(output)` would do the trick.

Comment: I tried setting the encoding but no luck. I will update the question with the code

Comment: @PixelCakeGames Are you trying to read a DOCX file as a string? If so, that won't work. DOCX is basically a ZIP file containing a bunch of XML files - it's the XML files that actually describe the document. You need to edit the XML files - the normal approach is to use the [OpenXML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) or one of the easier-to-use wrappers around it.

Comment: @PixelCakeGames definitely something to do with the text that you are reading...

Comment: @RB. Yes, it is a .DOCX file. I am in fact using OpenXML right now, but I came across aversion limitation that does not contain a GetXDocument() method on the MainDocumentPart. I figured reading a stream as text should be the same regardless, since I can edit the zip in notepad++ and it is okay. I'm mostly confused why the two streams are not the same when read as a string

Comment: A ZIP file doesn't have a text encoding, because it's not a text file. It's a binary file. I'm not even sure if you can just arbitrarily edit a zip file - it's likely you'll just end up corrupting it. I really don't think this is going to work for you. Why not unzip the file, and process the XML files instead - those *are* text files...

Comment: @RB. Good point. I will most likely do that since it's just XML inside the package

Comment: How is "Stream input" opened? If you want a byte-by-byte copy then open it as binary and it sounds as if you are not doing that. Also, if it were me, I would open the files using Visual Studio's "Binary Editor" to see what the truth is but it is highly likely that you just need to open the file as binary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your stream contains binary data that is not UTF-8. The default constructor for `StreamReader(Stream)` uses a UTF-8 decoder that replaces unrecognised byte sequences with the [Unicode replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), `U+FFFD`.

Let's assume the input stream contains the five bytes `41 80 81 82 7A`. Then `new StreamReader(input).ReadToEnd()` returns the string `"A���z"`, because `0x80` (and `0x81` and `0x82`) can't be decoded to a C# `char` using the UTF-8 encoding.

Calling `new StreamWriter(output).Write()` encodes that string to UTF-8 and writes it to the output stream. `U+FFFD` is encoded in UTF-8 as the three-byte sequence `EF BF BD`. So in this example, it would write out eleven bytes: `41 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 7A`.

The conversion of unrecognized bytes to � to `EF BF BD` explains why your stream grows in size when you read then write it.

The solution is to read and write `byte[]`, not to convert arbitrary binary data to a `string`.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for. I verified what you were saying by reading into a `byte[]` and checking the size. Very good insight